# How to read QR with kinect and get position of that QR?

Tags: ros, kinect, ar-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to locate qr code and want its position as well . I am using kinect v1 can any one help me in this scnerio .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243922/how-to-read-qr-with-kinect-and-get-position-of-that-qr?/) by [Qayyum](https://answers.ros.org/users/28005/qayyum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There exist a few ros packages for qr tracking.

1. [ar_track_alvar](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar)
2. [visp_auto_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/visp_auto_tracker)

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qayyum](https://answers.ros.org/users/28005/qayyum/) on 2016-09-18**:
But how can we use visp_auto_tracker with kinect any idea or any launch file